# react-router-dom back with previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an app with `react-router-dom` and use the `BrowserRouter` component.  In the app, I have route `/query-builder` that will essentially build a query string through picking values from tables etc.  Once the user has the query string built, they can navigate to `/search?q=<some querystring>` via the `useHistory()` hook from `react-router-dom` and `history.push('/search?q=${queryString}')`.

What I would like to know, is it possible to navigate back to the `/query-builder` route, via the browser back button, and see the page as it was just before I navigated to `/search` so the user could make amendments to the query.  What I am seeing at the moment, is that the query-builder component will go back to its initial state, as it is mounting again.

I could use redux to manage the query builder state and rehydrate the components from that, but I am wondering am I missing something available in the `react-router` / `react-router-dom` packages?

Comment: Is it important to use back button from browser or you can create your custom one?

Comment: yes it is, as the 'in app' back button will be navigating back through the history anyway

Answer (score 0):

Look like useContext is best variant to solve your problem. Save variables in query-builder, then you can easily go back without any scare) Also it'll work properly both in history.goBack() and browser back

Comment: ok, so same kind of idea as using redux, in that the state needs to be lifted to a more 'global' level